boot from usb hard drive
I try to install arch on a hard drive that is plugged by usb at the moment at my mac laptop. I will eventually have to switch the internal ssd with the usb one.
I basically follow this guide  : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_from_existing_Linux
When comming to install a boot manager, say GRUB, it looks like when I chose to boot from the usb drive holding the alt-key during power up, it launches the GRUB of the internal drive or at least its config file from there. Any suggestion on what to check ?

On a MAC you need to hold the OPTION key down at power up to let you select alternate boot devices.   At least that's how it was on my old machines; never used a new modern one!  (Hmm, https://support.apple.com/en-us/101578 says you need to keep the power button held down).

Sorry I edited to clarify that I hold the alt key then choose to boot from usb drive.
